# Modificar dato de un objeto

Tags: angular, momentjs

Tengo un objeto que me trae el consumo de una API, allí hay un start_date y un end_date, debo formatear con moment.js para que sea hora y minutos pero no lo logro hacer, este es el código que tengo pero no se como entrar al objeto y ajustar los campos mencionados teniendo en cuenta que esto lo debo llevar a un ngFor en el HTML.

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Iker",
        "description": "Blanditiis aut porro consequatur. Voluptatibus vitae accusamus blanditiis voluptatem. Eius consequatur et velit quidem sunt pariatur rem.",
        "start_date": "2021-11-07 08:00:00",
        "end_date": "2021-11-07 11:00:00",
        "status": "aprobation",
        "client_id": 31,
        "profesional_id": 22,
        "category_id": 2,
        "subcategory_id": 24,
        "created_at": "2021-11-26T13:40:18.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-26T13:40:18.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Ian",
        "description": "Et id sit porro repudiandae dolores qui perspiciatis. Et nulla at dolor. Ad ipsum quia quam amet aut. Et aliquid pariatur ut amet eligendi doloribus iusto.",
        "start_date": "2021-10-29 15:00:00",
        "end_date": "2021-10-29 17:00:00",
        "status": "reschedule",
        "client_id": 24,
        "profesional_id": 22,
        "category_id": 2,
        "subcategory_id": 28,
        "created_at": "2021-11-26T13:40:18.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-11-26T13:40:18.000000Z"
    }
]
```

```
this.scheduleService.load(this.professionalId).subscribe((response) => {
      
      this.events = response.events;
      this.loading = false;
      this.closeEvent(event);

    }, (errors) => {
      this.error = true;
      this.loading = false;
      this.closeEvent(event);
    });
```

```
<ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let event of events">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <p class="text-center">
            {{ event.start_date }}
          </p>
          <p class="text-center">
            a
          </p>
          <p class="text-center">
            {{ event.end_date }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
```

Comment: ¿Probaste algo como `{{moment(event.start_date).format('HH:mm')}}`?

Comment: Incluso dado el formato en que lo tienes, aunque no es buena práctica puedes usar métodos de string para obtener la porción con la hora y los minutos `{{start_date.slice(-8,-3)}}`

Comment: Realmente apenas estoy iniciando en el mundo de Angular, ya puse el código pero no funciona, no se si debo importar algo o hacer otra configuración

Comment: Obvio debes tener instalado e importado `moment` en tu proyecto, pensé eso ya era un hecho por tu pregunta. `moment` lo instalas usando `npm install moment --save`  e importas el paquete en el archivo donde vayas a usarlo, en este caso en donde declaras `ion-col`. Para importarlo usas `import * as moment from 'moment'`

Comment: Realmente si tengo esa importación pero por algún motivo que desconozco me sale este error en consola "ctx_r6.moment is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Si para lo único que quieres modificar el campo es para mostrar la hora en la aplicación, no necesitas usar momentjs. Puedes usar directamente la pipe `| date` de angular en el template.

En tu caso para formatear en 24h la puedes usar de la siguiente manera:

`{{ event.start_date | date: 'HH:mm' }}`

Te dejo enlace a documentación completa de la pipe por si necesitas ajustar el formato más.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe